# JavaScript preloading images is hurting performance

Tags: javascript, performance

I did a lighthouse audit of my website and one of the suggested improvements was to preload the LCP.

I did some research on preloading images and wrote the following function in my index.js.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { createBrowserRouter, Outlet, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";
// import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

// Components
import { Header } from "./Components/Header/Header";
import { Footer } from "./Components/Footer/Footer";
import { Alert } from "./Components/Alert/Alert";

// Context
import { AppProvider } from "./Context/appContext";

// Helpers
import ScrollToTop from "./Helpers/ScrollToTop";

// Images
import Designers from "./Images/designers.jpg";
import Developers from "./Images/developers.jpg";
import HostingAndSecurity from "./Images/hostingAndSecurity.jpg";

// Pages
import { AboutUs } from "./Pages/AboutUs/AboutUs";
import { Contact } from "./Pages/Contact/Contact";
import { Home } from "./Pages/Home/Home";
import { Services } from "./Pages/Services/Services";
import { Pricing } from "./Pages/Pricing/Pricing";

function Layout() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const images = [Designers, Developers, HostingAndSecurity];
    cacheImages(images);
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <ScrollToTop />
      <Alert />
      <Outlet />
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

async function cacheImages(srcArray) {
  const promises = await srcArray.map((src) => {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      const img = new Image();
      img.src = src;
      img.onload = resolve();
      img.onerror = reject();
    });
  });

  await Promise.all(promises);
}

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <Layout />,
    // errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/*",
        element: <Home />,
      },
      {
        path: "/about-us",
        element: <AboutUs />,
      },
      { path: "/contact", element: <Contact /> },
      {
        path: "/pricing",
        element: <Pricing />,
      },
      { path: "/services", element: <Services /> },
    ],
  },
]);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AppProvider>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </AppProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

However, doing this seems to have slowed my website down. I am a little confused about preloading images.

First off, my images are all included in my source code. Is this not ideal for load time?
Second, Where should I be calling my function to preload images.
Lastly, Does it make sense to preload all images?

Comment: this is open to opinions, anyway, I guess you could preload images in the "above the fold" portion of your page, then use lazy loading for the rest

Comment: "*`img.onload = resolve(); img.onerror = reject();`*" needs to be `img.onload = resolve; img.onerror = reject;`.

Comment: What framework are you using? What does happen when you `import Designers from "./Images/designers.jpg";`, what does your toolchain do with that?

Comment: I am using React